# Spam or something more sinister?

Tags: discussion

I checked the review queues as I usually do once per day. To my surprise, there were ~50 edits pending. All of them only changed minor elements, e.g. replacing quotes with the html equivalent. The comment contained an example.com e-mail address (which afaik do not actually work). I rejected all of them, but there are still some, so if you are reading this and are able to review edits, please do help.

Have you seen anything similar? Is this just spam, or could it be an attempt to exploit the SE system somehow?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I saw it also. I rejected them as spam/vandalism. Performing a huge number of small edits by anonymous user (possibly a script) is definitely an unhelpful behavior.

Generally my view is that we should not approve anonymous edits on posts of other users unless they make the post significantly better.

Comment: Doesn't stack exchange have an anti spam feature like reddit?

Comment: @Joshua, they do, but I don't think it catches things like these. I think there should have been a smaller number of permitted anonymous edits from an ip in a day.